# Drupal navigation in footer

Tags: navigation, drupal-7, render

On many sites you see the navigation with ALL links in the footer, in columns. But when you have MANY links you want some items to be in the same columns. (example: 12 items each with sub-items to be shown in 6 columns)

You can use:

```
<?php print(render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')))); ?>
```

But then you get nested UL elements.

Is there a way to get all links in DIV's? (not nested)

Example made in Drupal:
http://www.louvre.fr/

Comment: Why not style `ul` as `div`? Change display to block, list style to none etc...

Comment: Yeah, that is a possibility, but I have to much HTML that isn't needed for this... AND, the div's stay nested. But that isn't such a big problem I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Ul is being generated by your theme template files.

You can instead use views. I would generate the list in views. This allows me to format the output as div intead of ul.

This view I would then make it a block and then place it on the footer.

Hope this helps if not revert back.

Comment: yes you can use views to output the links then format the output as div.

Comment: No possibility to get navigation items in Views I think...

This is what is available in views:
Files, Revisions, Content, Taxonomy, Users, Local source, Theme

Answer (score 0):

I made some code that does what I wanted. Show the navigation (2 levels) in columns in the footer. If anyone has a better way for doing this, let me know!

```
$my_menu = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
$my_array = array();

foreach($my_menu as $my_item){
    $my_array[] = l(t($my_item['link']['link_title']), $my_item['link']['link_path'], array('attributes' => array('class' => array('level-1'))));
    foreach($my_item['below'] as $my_below){
        $my_array[] = l(t($my_below['link']['link_title']), $my_below['link']['link_path'], array('attributes' => array('class' => array('level-2'))));
    }
}

$my_totalcount = count($my_array);
$my_count = 0;
$my_column = 1;
$my_columns = 6;
$my_percolumn = ceil($my_totalcount / $my_columns);

foreach($my_array as $my_item){

    if($my_count == 0) echo '<div class="footer-column footer-column-'. $my_column++ .'">';
    echo $my_item;
    $my_count++;

    if($my_count == $my_percolumn){
        echo '</div>';
        $my_count = 0;
    }
}
```